# Async Await conversion

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await

Hoping to elicit some ideas on the converted api load func.  Somehow, it works, it's my first try.

I'm asking because I'd like to know if the error catch, from the do-catch, covers all the response stuff I removed.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var food: Food = Food(id: 0, uid: "", dish: "", description: "", ingredient: "", measurement: "")
    
    var body: some View {
        display
            .lineLimit(10)
            .task {
                do {
                    try await getRandomFood()
                } catch {
                    print("Error", error)   
                }
            }
    }
    
    // my converted 1st attempt, I wrote this from getRandomFood2() below
    func getRandomFood() async throws {
        let url = URL(string: "https://random-data-api.com/api/food/random_food")!
        
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url, delegate: nil)
            let food = try JSONDecoder().decode(Food.self, from: data)
            self.food = food
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
    
    // original func do-catch-ified above
    func getRandomFood2() async throws {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://random-data-api.com/api/food/random_food") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
        
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { fatalError("Error while fetching data") }
        let decodedFood = try JSONDecoder().decode(Food.self, from: data)
        food = decodedFood
        // print("Async decodedFood", decodedFood)
    }
    
    var display: some View {
        /* ...    */
   }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, there is no value to a `do`-`try`-`catch` if the only thing you do in the `catch` clause is to `throw error`. In your other example (w/o the `do`-`try`-`catch`) is fine. In fact, that additional validation of `statusCode` is prudent. But, then again, (a) it is not just 200 that is success, but any code b/w 200…299; and (b) you should not crash the app with `fatalError` just because the server did not report success, but rather just `throw` an appropriate error. E.g., https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/109550d14c73fc2226f6a77f53f022cf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the URL with this string literal cannot fail, it can be forced unwrapped.

And rather than aborting the code with an fatal error throw an `URLError`

```
func getRandomFood2() async throws {
    let url = URL(string: "https://random-data-api.com/api/food/random_food")!
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    
    guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { throw URLError(.badServerResponse) }
    food = try JSONDecoder().decode(Food.self, from: data)
}
```

Comment: I modified getRandomFood2(), and came up with getRandomFood() above.  Is there any difference between a URL error using the do-catch, and the getRandomFood2() version.  Say if the URL disappears, or becomes broken.  Pardon for not understanding.  But I am eliciting commentary for getRandomFood(), which I wrote.  Is getRandomFood() any good?

Comment: As I said this specific URL string cannot fail. If the URL *disappears* you get a server error, the URL is still valid. And the explicit `do - catch` block is redundant. `getRandomFood()` is fine without the `do - catch` block